# Subclass of an Abstract class, always call Abstract constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, abstract-class

I have an abstract class and a child class

```
abstract class abstractClass
{
    public int x;

    protected abstractClass(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
}

class childClass : abstractClass
{
    childClass(int x)
        : base(x)
    {
    }
}
```

I have many child classes like this one, where all of those classes always just call the common constructor `abstractClass1(int x)` by calling `base(x)` in their constructors.

When I want to add a new property to the constructor, for example another `int y`, I have to edit all of those classes and add the `y` as a parameter in every child's constructor plus the abstract class constructor.

Is there another way of doing this, considering I know beforehand that every child class will be using the abstract class constructor and won't be adding anything else ?

Comment: Depends on what `y` is.  Do the child classes need to be providing a value for `y`?  Will the constructor that only takes `x` continue to be valid?

Comment: @BJMyers yea of course the `y` will get its value set from the constructor, otherwise I would just add `y` to the abstract class an that would be it

Comment: You could add another constructor with the extra parameter, or set the parameter to a default value in the method signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one idea: make an `AbstractClassParameters` class:

```
class AbstractClassParameters {
    public int x { get; private set; }
    // add more parameters here
    public AbstractClassParameters(int x) {
        this.x = x;
        // add more initializers here
    }
}
```

Now you can pass an instance of `AbstractClassParameters` to the abstract class constructor, and every subclass can do the same, just passing it through.

```
abstract class abstractClass
{
    public int x;

    protected abstractClass(AbstractClassParameters p)
    {
        this.x = p.x;            
    }
}

class childClass : abstractClass
{
    childClass(AbstractClassParameters p) : base(p) { }
}
```

When you add a parameter, you only have to edit the `AbstractClassParameters` class and the `abstractClass`, not every subclass.

Comment: So every time a new field/property is added to the abstract base class the constructors for both AbstractClass **and** AbstractClassParameters will need to be extended; and every call to the constructor for AbstractClassParameters  will have to be modified instead of the equal number of calls to the constructor for AbstractClass. I fail to see how this is not actually a slight increase in work to support an extension.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The callsites (calls to subclass ctors) would have to be modified anyway, the base class would have to be modified anyway. There's one new class to modify, but no subclasses will have to be modified - so it should be a decrease in work proportional to the number of subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think you can do it any other way. You have to modify abstract class because you have to add new member y. You either modify the abstract class constructor to initialize the member y or you can create a property around y and let children initialize it inside the constructor.

Comment: I will modify the abstract constructor to initialize the `y` value. But that will still require me to modify `childClass(int x, int y)  : base(x,y)` for every child

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that most of the already existing sub-classes can easily accept a default value for the new property *y*. In this case add a new constructor for the base class with the new property initializer, and have the old constructor set the value of the new property to the common default value. Now only the sub-classes that require a non-default value for the new property need to call the extended base-class constructor.

Your example becomes:

```
abstract class abstractClass
{
    public int x { get; private set; }
    public int y { get; private set; }

    protected abstractClass(int x) : this(x, defaultY) {}
    protected abstractClass(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class childClass : abstractClass
{
    childClass(int x)
        : base(x)
    {
    }
}

class childClass2 : abstractClass
{
    childClass(int x, int y)
        : base(x,y)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: All sub-classes will have to set the `y` value. There is no default value.